# Exercise 2(a), Section 26 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, compactness, alternative-proof

> Show that in the finite-complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, every subspace is compact.

We can generalize the problem

> $(X,\mathcal{T}_{\text{cofinite}})$ and $Y\subseteq X$ $\Rightarrow$ $Y$ is compact.

**Proof:** $(X,\mathcal{T}_{\text{cofinite}})$. $Y\subseteq X$. Let $U=\{ U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_X |\alpha \in J$ and $U_\alpha \neq \emptyset \}$ be an open cover of $Y$ in $X$, i.e. $Y\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha$. Since $U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_X$ $\forall \alpha \in J$, either $X-U_\alpha$ is finite or $U_\alpha =\emptyset$. $U_\alpha \neq \emptyset$, $\forall \in J$. So $X-U_\alpha$ is finite, $\forall \alpha \in J$. If $Y=\emptyset$, then $Y$ is compact trivially.  Assume $Y\neq \emptyset$. Since $Y\neq \emptyset$, $\exists y\in Y$. $y\in U_{\alpha_0}$, for some $\alpha_0 \in J$. Let $Z=\{ z\in Y|z\notin U_{\alpha_0}\} \subseteq X-U_{\alpha_0}$. Since $X-U_{\alpha_0}$ is finite, $|Z|=n\in \Bbb{N}$. So $Z=\{z_1,..,z_n\}\subseteq X-U_{\alpha_0}$. $z_k \in U_{\alpha_k}$, $\forall 1\leq k\leq n$. Thus $\{ U_{\alpha_0}, U_{\alpha_1},…, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ is a finite subcover of $U$. Hence $Y$ is compact. **Is this proof correct?**

Potential approach(2) is to use theorem 26.9 definition of compactness.

Comment: what is the topology on $Y$?

Comment: @00GB subspace topology

Comment: your open cover must be taken from the subspace $Y$ NOT from $\tau_X$

Comment: @00GB look lemma 26.1

Comment: $Y$ is given as an arbitrary subset of $X$. There is nothing to indicate it is not empty as you claim. And there was no need to make that assumption. Any arbitrary member of $U$ can be used as $U_{\alpha_0}$. And one word of advice: ditch $J$ and the $\alpha$ indexing. It just makes everything less clear than saying $\mathscr U$ is an open cover, choosing some $U$ in it to start, and $U_i$ to cover the finite number of points in $Y - U$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair emptyset is trivially compact. That’s why I assumed non empty set $Y$. I am use to $J$ and $\alpha$ indexing.

Comment: When you write up a proof, it is not to *convince yourself* the result is true, but rather to convince *others*. So "I know this case is true, and don't need to mention it" does not work. Your proof is incomplete unless you handle all cases in it. Handling a trivial case is trivial to do, so there is no good reason of excluding mention of it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Okay I will edit my post.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Do you how to do this problem using theorem 26.9 definition of compactness?

Comment: My copy of Munkres is at least an edition behind, and he did a massive reordering between those editions. You'll have to tell me what definition you are referring to.

Comment: It looks correct to me, albeit messy

Comment: @PaulSinclair $X$ is compact $\iff$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is collection of closed subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal{C}$ have finite intersection property, then $\bigcap \mathcal{C} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Let $C \in \mathcal C$. then $C$ is closed and therefore finite. Suppose $\bigcap \mathcal C = \emptyset$. then for each $c \in C$, there is some $K_c \in \mathcal C$ such that $c \notin K_c$. But then $\{C\}\cup\{K_c \mid c \in C\}$ is a finite collection of sets of $\mathcal C$ with $C\cap \bigcap_{c \in C} K_c = \emptyset$. Therefore $\mathcal C$ does not have the finite intersection property.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I also tried to use contradiction as my first attempt to prove this way. $C$ is closed in $Y$ not in $X$. So $Y-C=Y\cap U$, where $U\in \mathcal{T}_X$. What $K_c$ represent?

Comment: I said what $K_c$ is: some set in $\mathcal C$ which does not contain $c$. If there were no such set, then $c\in\bigcap C$ which I had assumed was empty at this point. As for $Y$ vs $X$, you'll note I don't mention $X$. $Y$ is compact in $X$ if and only if it is compact under the subspace topology inherited from $X$. And since any closed set $C$ in $Y$ is $C = C'\cap Y$ for some closed set $C'$ in $X$, But $C'$ is finite, so $C$ is as well. That is, the subspace topology on $Y$ is cofinite. so I was just working in $Y$, not $X$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I’m sorry I got messed up with $C$ and $\mathcal{C}$. Thank you so much for the answer. You can write your above comment as answer. I will accept it.